# Multiplying pointer address

Tags: c, pointers

So basically bst in this case is a float pointer (I am using it for an array implementation of a binary search tree). I need to insert elements, left node = 2i, right node = 2i+1, so bst=bst*2 means I am trying to change the pointer of the current index of the array. It doesn't work. How do I make it work? Addition of pointers is allowed yet not multiplicatoin. Why?!

For more information, see [my whole program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443922/inserting-into-a-binary-search-tree-array-based-recursively-without-taking-in).

Comment: Where, exactly, do you think `bst * 2` points? You're multiplying a memory address by `2`.

Answer (score 4):

Multiplication on pointers isn't allowed because there's no use for it.  If you have a variable that's located at, say, address `0x4f2c18e9` — that's a pointer value — there's no reason to expect that address `0x9e5831d2` (that's `0x4f2c18e9 * 2`) is a valid place to store data.

Answer (score 0):

the `bst + 1` means "the next float after this float", the compiler knows bst is a float, so it knows how many distance should move to get the next element.

But what is a "Multiply to pointer"? does it has a meaning?

If you means the two times far from the beginning of an array, then it's a index concept. As an array index, like `arr[i * 2  + 1]`, it first calculate the `i * 2 + 1` which means the distance, then apply it to the `[]` operator.

So, if you want to do something like this, you should first calculate the distance from this element to the beginning, then do your multiplying, then add it back in the final. An sample code is as follow:

```
BStree bst, h;
......
size_t i = bst - h;
BStree pLeftNode = bst + i * 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is using recursion to keep the base on the bottom of the stack and pushing on the next location using your BStree. You just pass on the next location using a simple test:

```
void bstree_insert(BStree bst, float key){
    long int ibst = (int)bst;
    ibst *= 2;
    float * nbst = (float *)ibst;
    if(*bst == -1)
        *bst = key;
    else if(*bst == key)
        ;
    else if(*bst > key)
        bstree_insert(nbst+1, key);
    else if(*bst < key)
        bstree_insert(nbst+2, key);

    return;
}
```

From the way you've described it, this is what you want.

HOWEVER!

I don't think your instructor would want you messing with memory like this. It's not something any level of programmer should be doing unless you want your computer to turn into a transformer, change into Optimus Prime, and kick your tush into next year.

So...I would suggest that you go back and carefully re-read the instructions for your problem.

Comment: Of course it's going to crash! I said in the answer that this code messes with memory in a way that NOBODY should ever do! You need to use the bstree_traverse function to find a way to remember your index.

Comment: Why are you trying to edit my post, OP? Just because you can't read the part that says that my example, despite being what you're asking for, is something that should never be attempted doesn't mean that it's incorrect.